# How to establish a TCP/IP connection without opening ports?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, p2p

I never figured this one out and I've been programming for years. How do P2P programs like chat programs or torrent programs manage to create connections between two peers without peers opening any ports? I know I haven't opened up a port for Skype yet I can send and receive large files to and from my friends, and I'm pretty sure all those gigabytes don't go through Skype servers. Or do they?

What about torrenting? I can upload data to peers and I haven't opened any ports either.

I'm pretty sure the answer will be language-nonspecific, but in case I'm wrong, I code mostly in C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP

Comment: Use a sniffer to find out. Anyhow, "opening" a port (i.e. calling listen() on it) is just a way to establish a connection. Once connected, the two sides are peers, i.e. both can send and receive any kind of data.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt "Opening a port" in this context isn't `listen()`, but rather changing the configuration of one or more firewalls to allow traffic with a specific port number to transit the firewall(s).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to "open a port" for inbound connections.  One peer will open a listening port, then instruct the other peer to connect to it.  If the connection fails, the peers will usually swap roles and try again.  If the connection still fails, then either the transfer is aborted, or a server relay is used if feisable.

For each listening peer, if the port is behind a router/firewall, the peer can either programmably instruct the router/firewall to open a port for forwarding inbound connections to the peer (some routers support uPNP for that, and some firewalls have their own API), or the peer can try using various "hole punching" techniques to trick the router/firewall into opening a forwarding port (some routers/firewalls are not susceptible to this).

Read this for more details: [How Skype & Co. get round firewalls](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html)

Comment: Oh... I googled hole punching. Now that makes sense. That's very sneaky. Thanks! :P